# Databinding to a View Model not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, data-binding, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have an AJAX Accordion Control sitting on my Web Form. I have a Asp.Net Label sitting inside an Accordion Pane. I want to databind the text property of the label to a View Model I have running.

The Label Text Property never seems to databind with the View Model? It will work perfectly if I pull the label outside of the Accordion Pane, but not inside?

This works:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Model.Program.NameVisible.ToString() %>' />
```

This does not:

```
<asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane2" runat="server">
    <Header>
        Advanced Search
    </Header>
    <Content>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlAdvancedSearch" runat="server">
            <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%" runat="server">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Model.Program.NameVisible.ToString() %>' />                                
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </Content>
</asp:AccordionPane>
```

Any ideas or workarounds?

Thanks.

Update: This apparently does not work when nested inside any AJAX Controls. I have had the same issue with the binding not taking place inside a ModalPopUpExtender as well.

Comment: Still working on this, some insight would be helpful!

Comment: Can you include code where Model is set as a data source and DataBind is invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataBind` of the `Accordion` control does not invoke `DataBind` for each of the explicitly defined, custom `AccordionPane` controls. It instead will build the panes, as per the answer provided by Jupaol, using templates.

In your example, you will need to explicitly call `DataBind` on the control you want bound, or on a parent which will invoke databinding on all children. So, in your example, calling `pnlAdvancedSearch.DataBind()` would suffice to bind your label, and any other controls within the search panel.

I feel it worthwhile to add, however, that it also seems like it would be simpler to replace your `<asp:Label>` control entirely with a simple:

```
<%: Model.Program.NameVisible.ToString() %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way

First of all the `Accordion` control does support data binding:

> The Accordion can also be databound. Simply specify a data source through the DataSource or DataSourceID properties and then set your data items in the HeaderTemplate and ContentTemplate properties.

[Source](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Accordion/Accordion.aspx)

Example:

#### Output

[image]

#### ASPX

```
<ajax:Accordion runat="server" ID="ajax22"  RequireOpenedPane="true"
    HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
    HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected"
    ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
>
    <ContentTemplate>
        Even cooler content
        <br />
        <asp:Label Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Something") %>' ID="lbl" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        Cool header
        <br />
        <asp:Label Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Something") %>' ID="lbl" runat="server" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
</ajax:Accordion>
```

#### ASPX code behind

You need to specify the `Accordion.DataSource` property, this property only supports `IEnumerable` or `IListSource`, therefore you would need to bind your accordion as follows:

```
this.ajax22.DataSource = new[] { this.Model };

this.DataBind();
```

#### Model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyModel()
    {
        this.Something = "plop!";
    }

    public string Something { get; set; }
}
```

---

When you bind your `Accordion`, a number of `AccordionPanes` are created to represent each bound item.

If you specify additional custom `AccordionPanes`, when you apply binding as specified above, these `AccordionPanes` will be ignored and won't be rendered.

Comment: This works but does not fulfill my needs. I have two custom panes in my Accordion and when I do as you suggest I lose those custom panes (like you said I would) which is not acceptable in this case. @MikeGuthrie